# Papa parse returns Data array in which everything is converted to string

Tags: javascript, reactjs, papaparse

I am parsing .CSV to `Papa.parse` with `React`, i am getting output something like this:

```
[
  {Year: "1929", BMW: "1896", Toyots: "9547", Mercedes: "4881"},
  {Year: "1930", BMW: "6548", Toyots: "4741", Mercedes: "8096"},
  {Year: "1931", BMW: "5013", Toyots: "6269", Mercedes: "3908"},
  {Year: "1932", BMW: "2468", Toyots: "9858", Mercedes: "1623"},
  {Year: "1933", BMW: "3364", Toyots: "5595", Mercedes: "8638"},
  {Year: "1934", BMW: "2032", Toyots: "2570", Mercedes: "8041"},
  {Year: "1935", BMW: "3579", Toyots: "6886", Mercedes: "6938"},
  {Year: "1936", BMW: "2865", Toyots: "3336", Mercedes: "1996"}
]
```

The problem is Papa.parse coverts everything to `string` under double quotation mark!

How can we convert back them to `number`? (if they were number in their original form! **Problem is that some of the `Field` may not have `number` type, say location or address or name: they are `string` typo**)

Or Is there any configuration for preventing `Papa.parse` to do so?

Comment: in a csv file, everything are treated as strings. you will have to manually convert them back to their "native" types.

Comment: try to remove the double quotation in the csv for numbers

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I convert a string into an integer in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1133770/how-do-i-convert-a-string-into-an-integer-in-javascript)

Comment: @Isaac Sorry, but my problem was different and i got the solution, thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Enable the `dynamicTyping` option to retain numbers:

```js
const csv = "Year,BMW,Toyota,Mercedes,Location\n1929,1896,9547,4881,Germany"
const csvData = Papa.parse(csv, {header:true, dynamicTyping: true}).data

console.log(typeof csvData[0].Year);
console.log(typeof csvData[0].Location);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/PapaParse/4.5.0/papaparse.min.js">
</script>
```

Comment: this is correct answer. user don't need to do .map, isNan and so on, this handled by the library

Answer (score 3):

You can use `map()` to transform the array items into number:

```js
var papa =[
{Year: "1929", BMW: "1896", Toyots: "9547", Mercedes: "4881"},
{Year: "1930", BMW: "6548", Toyots: "4741", Mercedes: "8096"},
{Year: "1931", BMW: "5013", Toyots: "6269", Mercedes: "3908"},
{Year: "1932", BMW: "2468", Toyots: "9858", Mercedes: "1623"},
{Year: "1933", BMW: "3364", Toyots: "5595", Mercedes: "8638"},
{Year: "1934", BMW: "2032", Toyots: "2570", Mercedes: "8041"},
{Year: "1935", BMW: "3579", Toyots: "6886", Mercedes: "6938"},
{Year: "1936", BMW: "2865", Toyots: "3336", Mercedes: "1996"}
];

papa = papa.map(item => {
  item.Year = Number(item.Year);
  item.BMW = Number(item.BMW);
  item.Toyots = Number(item.Toyots);
  item.Mercedes = Number(item.Mercedes);
  return item;
});
console.log(papa);
```

You might be interested in the following approach as well:

```js
var papa = [
  {Year: "1929", BMW: "1896", Toyots: "9547", Mercedes: "4881", Status : "Test"},
  {Year: "1930", BMW: "6548", Toyots: "4741", Mercedes: "8096"},
  {Year: "1931", BMW: "5013", Toyots: "6269", Mercedes: "3908"},
  {Year: "1932", BMW: "2468", Toyots: "9858", Mercedes: "1623"},
  {Year: "1933", BMW: "3364", Toyots: "5595", Mercedes: "8638"},
  {Year: "1934", BMW: "2032", Toyots: "2570", Mercedes: "8041"},
  {Year: "1935", BMW: "3579", Toyots: "6886", Mercedes: "6938"},
  {Year: "1936", BMW: "2865", Toyots: "3336", Mercedes: "1996"}
];

papa = papa.map(item => {
  Object.keys(item).forEach(k => item[k] = isNaN(item[k])? item[k] : Number(item[k]));
  return item;
});
console.log(papa);
```

Answer (score 2):

Make use of **isNaN** to check number if so then return parse that number string else return as it is.

```js
var papa =[
{Year: "1929", BMW: "1896", Toyots: "9547", Mercedes: "4881","location":"pune"},
{Year: "1930", BMW: "6548", Toyots: "4741", Mercedes: "8096"},
{Year: "1931", BMW: "5013", Toyots: "6269", Mercedes: "3908"},
{Year: "1932", BMW: "2468", Toyots: "9858", Mercedes: "1623"},
{Year: "1933", BMW: "3364", Toyots: "5595", Mercedes: "8638"},
{Year: "1934", BMW: "2032", Toyots: "2570", Mercedes: "8041"},
{Year: "1935", BMW: "3579", Toyots: "6886", Mercedes: "6938"},
{Year: "1936", BMW: "2865", Toyots: "3336", Mercedes: "1996"}
];

papa = papa.map(item => {
  const keys = Object.keys(item);
  let newObj={}
  keys.map((m)=>{
      newObj[m] = isNaN(item[m]) ? item[m] : parseInt(item[m])
  })
  return newObj
});
console.log(papa);
```

Answer (score 0):

For new comers:
You can use papa.parse transform method.

```
 Papa.parse(fileUpload.file, {
        download: true,
        header: true,
        dynamicTyping: true,
        transform: (value: string) => removeQuotes(value)}
)



export function removeQuotes(str: string) {
    if ((str.startsWith('"') && str.endsWith('"')) || (str.startsWith("'") && str.endsWith("'"))) {
        return str.slice(1, -1); // Remove the first and last character
    }
    return str;
}
```